# Can you make your Facebook statuses/posts "really public"?

Tags: facebook

I would like to make my Facebook posts "really public": indexable by Google, viewable without a Facebook account.

Is it possible? If not, I may have finally found the killer feature of Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Facebook user profiles, this is not possible. Though, it is possible if you have a Facebook page and no age/country restrictions set in permissions.

Answer (score 2):

No.  This isn't possible.  Even if you make post public and enable subscriptions (for example, [Ryan Seacrest](http://www.facebook.com/ryanseacrest)) you can only see his public posts if you actually log in.  Facebook is mistaken here.  Public subscriptions should mean public!!!!